# typo3 7, bootstrap_package, RealUrl and own extension

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3-7.6.x, realurl, typo3-extensions

I setup a typo3 with the bootstrap_package; created with the extension builder my own extension and installed realURL with auto conf and hoped it would work. It did not. I tried to write my own conf but it is ignored but somewhere the page settings are beeing made.

The auto generated file already had a no_cache setting but it isn't beeing interpreted and my own settings are also not used but the page settings are.
any ideas?

my url currently looks like this:

```
http://localhost/test/sub/
?tx_test_shop[product]=1
&tx_test_shop[action]=show
&tx_test_shop[controller]=Product
&cHash=49495417a4d9eb25776b945d2123bbdf
```

my settings:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZbKC.jpg

Full file:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
'http://localhost/' => array(
        'init'        =>
            array(
                'appendMissingSlash'  => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
                'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
            ),
        'pagePath'    =>
            array(
                'rootpage_id' => '2',
            ),
        'fileName'    =>
            array(
                'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
                'acceptHTMLsuffix'          => 1,
                'index'                     =>
                    array(
                        'print' =>
                            array(
                                'keyValues' =>
                                    array(
                                        'type' => 98,
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            ),
        'preVars'     =>
            array(
                0 =>
                    array(
                        'GETvar'   => 'no_cache',
                        'valueMap' =>
                            array(
                                'nc' => '1',
                            ),
                        'noMatch'  => 'bypass',
                    ),
                1 =>
                    array(
                        'GETvar'   => 'L',
                        'valueMap' =>
                            array(
                                'de' => '1',
                            ),
                        'noMatch'  => 'bypass',
                    ),
            ),
        'postVarSets' => array(
            '_DEFAULT' => array(
                'p' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_test_shop[product]',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar'   => 'tx_test_shop[controller]',
                        'valueMap' => array(
                            'Product' => 66,
                        ),

                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar'   => 'tx_test_shop[action]',
                        'valueMap' => array(
                            'list' => 'list',
                            'show' => 'show',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'page'    => array(
                    0 =>
                        array(
                            'GETvar' => 'page',
                        ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: [TYPO3 - realurl is ignoring created/own extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42320404/typo3-realurl-is-ignoring-created-own-extension)

What I did was:

- I deactivated and removed the extension.
- Deleted typo3temp and all realurl tables.
- Cleared caches in InstallTool
- Installed the extension again.

-> Now everything works as expected

*Please make copies of records and tables before removing them just in case.

It might be due to the installation order:

"The order you will install the extensions matters! Make sure the RealURL extension is installed first, then the bootstrap package and afterwards the rest of the extensions which contain RealURL rules including your new one." (Source: https://aimeos.org/tips/tag/realurl/ )