# TYPO3 - realurl is ignoring created/own extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

I have a running TYPO3 installation (7.6) with with the latest realurl and news extension. All working fine. I now created a simple extension tx_ffscarexample and struggling to manipulate the paths for it. In tx_ffscarexample I have 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete' actions. Now, when first calling the page /car-example/ with the List View ... my path looks like:

List View

```
/car-example/
```

... I get all records showing in a table.

But already when I hover over the links I get like

```
/car-example/?tx_ffscarexample_carlist[car]=3&tx_ffscarexample_carlist[action]=show&tx_ffscarexample_carlist[controller]=Car&cHash=0b3f5b986dsdf95f33465e3d324e1e83a
```

When I then go into a detail view ... I get e.g.

Show View

```
/car-example/?tx_ffscarexample_carlist[car]=3&tx_ffscarexample_carlist[action]=show&tx_ffscarexample_carlist[controller]=Car&cHash=0b3f5b236dd5295f5f6234d324e1e83a
```

New View

```
/car-example/?tx_ffscarexample_carlist[action]=new&tx_ffscarexample_carlist[controller]=Car&cHash=4df2347378f318530423761f7627394a6
```

Edit View

```
/car-example/?tx_ffscarexample_carlist%5Bcar%5D=15&tx_ffscarexample_carlist%5Baction%5D=edit&tx_ffscarexample_carlist%5Bcontroller%5D=Car&cHash=72344542eaf1c64c12347dd3c7714
```

List View

```
/car-example/?tx_ffscarexample_carlist[action]=list&tx_ffscarexample_carlist[controller]=Car&cHash=23d56247c27805c2c234c8c23353c7e
```

In realurl_conf.php I've added for the extension:

...

```
    'postVarSets' => array(
            '_DEFAULT' => array(
                    'car' => array(
                            array(
                                    'GETvar' => 'tx_ffscarexample_carlist[action]',
                                    'valueMap' => array(
                                            'list' => 'list',
                                            'show' => 'show',
                                            'new' => 'new',
                                            'edit' => 'edit',
                                            'create' => 'create',
                                            'delete' => 'delete',
                                            'update' => 'udpate'
                                    ),
                                    'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'GETvar' => 'tx_ffscarexample_carlist[controller]',
                                    'valueMap' => array(
                                            'car' => 'car',
                                    ),
                                    'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'GETvar' => 'tx_ffscarexample_carlist[car]',
                                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                                            'table' => 'tx_ffscarexample_domain_model_car',
                                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                                            'alias_field' => 'name',
                                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                                            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                                            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                                    'strtolower' => 1,
                                                    'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                                            ),
                                            'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                                            'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                                            'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                                            'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                                            'autoUpdate' => 1,
                                            'expireDays' => 180,
                                    )
                            )                                
                    ),

            ),
    )
```

...

What am I missing?

What I would like to have is sth like ...

```
/car-example/car/
/car-example/car/new

/car-example/car/audi/
/car-example/car/audi/edit/
/car-example/car/audi/delete/
/car-example/car/bmw/
/car-example/car/bmw/edit/
/car-example/car/bmw/delete/
```

Seems like here are similar issues:

[typo3 7, bootstrap_package, RealUrl and own extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781562/typo3-7-bootstrap-package-realurl-and-own-extension?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. What I did was:

- I deactivated and removed the extension.
- Deleted typo3temp and all realurl tables.
- Cleared caches in InstallTool
- Installed the extension again. 
  -> Now everything works as expected

*Please make copies of records and tables before removing them just in case.

It might be due to the installation order:

"The order you will install the extensions matters! Make sure the RealURL extension is installed first, then the bootstrap package and afterwards the rest of the extensions which contain RealURL rules including your new one." (Source: https://aimeos.org/tips/tag/realurl/ )